# Changing font color for some of the values enclosed in a <td> tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a table, filled with data from an API. In that, I have several cells consisting of data. The code for creating table is as follows:

```
<td class="myclass">
    <?php
        $myvar = explode(" ", $json["data"]);
        foreach($myvar as $v) {
            echo " " . round($v);
        }
    ?>
</td>
```

The cells may consist more than one value I want to apply style for each value.

Is there any way to apply different font colour to different values printed by the foreach loop. For example, green if the value is below 10, red if above 20 and else - orange. What I found was:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mytable td.singlevalue').each(function(){
        if (Number($(this).text()) > 50) {
            $(this).css('color','#f00');
        }
    });
});
```

and it works great, but only for cells which contain a single value.

Example of the `<td>` in question: `<td class="myclass">62 69 62 62 68 66</td>`

Comment: Could you please show a sample of your table HTML. The PHP is not very helpful.

Comment: So you're saying that you have multiple numbers in the same column, and you want each of those individual numbers colored differently?

Comment: You could try a switch case method or ternary / nested ternary. The latter also works in JS.

Comment: The question about colouring the row or each cell present in the table which has number?

Comment: @PatrickQ yes, that's exactly the goal. I posted an example output of the <td> tag

Comment: Does your number is coming in one column or other too?

Comment: You'll have to put something like a span around each number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just update your PHP like as follows:

```
<td class="myclass">
  <?php
$myvar = explode(" ", $json["data"]);
foreach ($myvar as $v) {
?>
   <span class='<?php
    echo round($v) > 50 ? ' green ' : 'red ';
?>'>
          <?php
    echo " " . round($v);
?>
</span>
    <?php
}
?>
</td>
```

Comment: I was thinking about using php to check the values as they are echoed but was't sure how it would assign the color. I tried the code snippet but I get an error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL)`

Comment: I already updated the answer please update! as well as define the class named green and red in the CSS.

Comment: Almost there but not quite. Something is not right - it applies the span  tag to each individual value but the classname is empty : `<span class=''>62</span>`